What are the maamorim of the Frierdiker Rebbe that are learned regularly in Chabad yeshivot?
I know the classic Rashab maamorim like Ranat and Samech Vav, but what about of the Frierdiker? I’m wondering specifically from ת״ש-תש״ג

For Jews in America, the entire ת״ש series is recommended, meaning from ת׳ש through תש׳י.

Outside of the yeshiva curriculum elite dibburim is highly encouraged to be learned.

Welcome to MiYodeya MarMani and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
